# ORA-01758: table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, oracle11g, entity-framework-migrations

Im working with EF CodeFirst Migration under Oracle
I met a strange problem when Im trying to add a new Boolean non-null column into the exsiting table

```
AddColumn("SYSTEM.ERP_MST_WAREHOUSE", "IS_ACTIVE", c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 1, scale: 0,defaultValue:1));//*it does not work *//
```

the error is [image]

some suggested

```
AddColumn("SYSTEM.ERP_MST_WAREHOUSE", "IS_ACTIVE", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false,defaultValue:true));//*does not work either*//
```

Finally I solved by

```
Sql("ALTER TABLE SYSTEM.ERP_MST_WAREHOUSE ADD IS_ACTIVE NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL");
```

It seemed like the 'defaultValue' didn't work.
Any suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: When I do that in Oracle, I use the last syntax you posted (which *works*, as you said). Just a remark, if I may: it seems that you're doing something in SYSTEM schema - you'd rather **not** do that. SYS and SYSTEM are special, don't mess up with them.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Littlefoot  .For your remarks.

Comment: Just as an additional note to what Littlefoot has already said, you can't create table columns with a datatype of BOOLEAN - that's not a valid SQL datatype.

Comment: Please don't assume someone's gender, unless it's very, very obvious. "Mr" is the wrong title for me. You can just use someone's handle to refer to them on StackOverflow; no need for any titles or honorifics.

Comment: I‘m so SORRY about that

Comment: That's ok; I understood you meant to be respectful *{:-)